# How can I debug a websocket connection?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

When running within a testcafe test, upon loading an app that tries to connect to a websocket, I receive an error in the console of "Connection closed before receiving a handshake response"

This prevents most of the app from working.

How can I get additional information about what the final request that testcafe is making after url-rewriting? I'd like to see exactly what url & headers it's sending to try to connect.

Simple example:

```html
import { ClientFunction, Selector } from "testcafe";

fixture`Getting Started`.page("https://torus.qa.argos.education/session/new");

test("Example error", async (t) => {
  await t.debug();
});
```

I've tried chrome with both non ssl and self signed certificate mode, and also tried disabling web security. Firefox gives the same error.

Comment: I reproduced the WebSocket error and created an issue that describes this behavior in our GitHub repository: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/2751. Please subscribe to this issue to receive updates about our progress.

I discovered that the webpage functions as expected when I open it in a browser in a regular way. This means that the most probable cause of this error is how TestCafe alters the page code. If you debug the WebSocket, you will probably see the requests with the URL and headers unfamiliar to you, so it's unlikely that this information will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

We released a new TestCafe version (v2.3.0), which includes [experimental proxyless mode](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404237/guides/experimental-capabilities/proxyless-mode). This mode uses native browser automation. In Proxyless mode, a few issues are already fixed. This issue should also be fixed in Proxyless mode.

Unfortunately, I was not able to test your web site since the URL you shared is no longer available. Would you please check if your sample is working correctly in v2.3.0 with experimental proxyless mode enabled?
This option is available in all interfaces:

```js
// Command-line
testcafe chrome tests --experimental-proxyless

 

// Programmatic
const testcafe = await createTestCafe({ experimentalProxyless: true });
    
// Configuration file
{
   "experimentalProxyless": "true"
}
```

Please keep in mind that this mode is still experimental and is implemented only in Google Chrome. It will not work correctly if you run tests in a non-Chrome browser or in a combination of other browsers.